# what does ::SomeMethod() Mean - scope resolution operator

Tags: c++

I know that `::` is the scope resolution operator. However what does it mean if something simply starts with a scope resolution operator. I know that something needs to be placed before the scope resolution operator (either a class name or a namespace). What if there is nothing before a scope resolution operator. For instance `::Method()`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It refers to the global scope.  For example:

```
int count = 0;

int main(void) {
  int count = 0;
  ::count = 1;  // set global count to 1
  count = 2;    // set local count to 2
  return 0;
}
```